# mobile web app - what is considered to be the best size to design my app?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am a wen developer, I have now started a new project for the mobile platform using jquery mobile.

As a web developer I know that handling different resolutions and screen sizes is quite a pain, I also know that the most popular solution is to design your application for a fix size and add free spacing to the right and left of the application. As much as I know in web development this 1024 X 768 .

What is the equivalent to the mobile platform?

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about mobile phones or tablet computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQM is designed to be flexible for Mobile and Tablet design.

If you need to target a particular resolution you can run a media query, Docs here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/mediahelpers.html

If you look at the jQm Demo site ([here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/)) on a Mobile or Tablet device, the markup is the same for both and jQM renders the site for each device type